# Push image and access through Public IP

Tags: azure, azure-devops, pipeline, azure-aks

I am using Azure Devops to build and push image to container. Image has been pushed successfully. I have two tasks `kubectl run` for deployment and `kubectl expose` to expose deployment as service but i cant access service my api service through public ip.

My task commands are :

```
kubectl run deploymentname --image --port

Kubectl expose deployment deploymentname --type =loadbalancer --port 80 --targetport 8090 --name service name –
```

Comment: so, have you got access to kubernetes? does the service actually create a load balancer? does service have valid endpoints? is the container running? is it listening on the port you are exposing?

Comment: I have checked load balancer is there , external IP , end points are there . Should i have to add ingress controller ?

Comment: no, service should be enough. what about the other questions? is your app listening on that port in the pod?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: if you app isnt listening on that port you need to fix that

Comment: Now listening on: http://[::]:80 i am getting this